# How can I observe changes in the AllowedFileTypes of FileSavePickerUI?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

When you register your app as a file-save picker, you get a `FileSavePickerActivatedEventArgs` in your **App.xaml.cs**:

```
protected override void OnFileSavePickerActivated(FileSavePickerActivatedEventArgs e)
{
   var filter = e.FileSavePickerUI.AllowedFileTypes; // This is IReadOnlyList<string>
}
```

When the user selects a different set of file-types:

[image]

How will I get the notification that the collection changed? `FileSavePickerUI.AllowedFileTypes` is not observable. Is there a trick?

**@MethodMan**, in Windows Store Apps you can register your app to be a FileSavePicker, which allows it to show up as an option when other apps want to "Save as...". The UI that contains your app is outside your control, like the drop down for "Save as type" (look at photo above). This drop down contains the values for `FileSavePickerUI.AllowedFileTypes`. When the user changes this selection, I need to get a notification. Except... I can't. I can't seem to find any way to observe this change.

---

Looks like there's a bug in Windows 10 as of (Oct 2015) where the `FileNameChanged` event does not fire when the type is changed. This only seems to work in Windows 8.

Comment: can you clarify what it is you're trying to do.. if you are worried that the user will save the type as something different  can you not set up a filter.. ? can you show how the save as file type filter is being set..?

Comment: @MethodMan, response above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`FileNameChanged` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.provider.filesavepickerui.filenamechanged.aspx) is documented as being raised whenever the file type changes.

Comment: That's what I thought. But, it's not raised. The event is only raised when the user actually types a different name in the text box.

Comment: Peter, looks like this event works in Windows 8, but not Windows 10 UWP.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look and file a bug.